# How do I vertically and horizontally center align a button with CSS on a responsive website?

Tags: html, css, button

As shown in the picture, the button is left-aligned by default. What CSS property can I use to center align a button on a responsive website? Note: I am not sure if I pasted the correct code. Please let me know if this is an issue for you. Thanks in advance.

[image: The image shows the button left-aligned. I would like the button to be horizontally and vertically centered in the section of my responsive website.]

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">              
         <div class="col-sm-6 wow slideInUp">
            <br>
            <a class="btn btn-theme-primary btn-lg" href="http://websiteurl.com/">Click Here</a>
            <br><br>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

enclose the button inside the `<div>` tag with a style of `text-align: center` and add style on `<a></a>` with `margin: 0 auto`.

it should be like this

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">              
         <div class="col-sm-12 wow slideInUp">
            <br>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <a class="btn btn-theme-primary btn-lg" style="margin: 0 auto;" href="http://websiteurl.com/">Click Here</a>
                <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks kcNeko. I tested out your code but I am doing something wrong. Can you please correct me? <div style="text-align: center">
   <a style="margin: 0 auto"><a class="btn btn-theme-primary btn-lg" href="http://mywebsite.com/">Click Here</a>
</div>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bd8nudts/1/ try looking at this fiddle. it should work.

Comment: see my updated answer. Or changing `col-sm-6` to `col-sm-12` to center it within the whole 100% width.

Comment: kcNeko, it did not work. The button moved slightly to the right. That's about it. It is still very far from being centered. I tried to do the following but there was no effect: .row { text-align: center; }

Comment: change class from `col-sm-6` to `col-sm-12` to make it the 100% width.

Comment: It didn't work when I copy and paste your code. I am not sure what's wrong. I followed your instruction.

Comment: actually it worked, however you have a class of `col-lg-6` to your code which only occupies 50% of the screen width.

Comment: I tried it with your update on multiple  attempts and it didn't work. The HTML box I was using formats the button differently. I now used a different HTML box and it worked. Now, I have too much padding at the bottom. Thanks for your help kcNeko